# what does BuildCommDCB actually do?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, msdn

I've just started doing some Win32 programming and I'm confused on the function:

```
BOOL BuildCommDCB(LPCTSTR szSettings, LPDCB lpDCB);
```

The description of the LPDCB struct states that "it points to the DCB structure in which the control settings information is
returned". But my question is how is the DCB structure returned when the return value is a `BOOL`?

Answer (score 4):

`LPDCB` is a *pointer* to a structure you provide<sup>(1)</sup>, and `BuildCommDCB()` will populate that structure, *as well as* returning a success indicator.

It's no different to the function:

```
int setTo13AndReturn42 (int *pInt) {
    *pInt = 13;
    return 42;
}
```

which, when called with:

```
int i1 = -1;
int i2 = setTo13AndReturn42 (&i1);
printf ("%d %d\n", i1, i2);
```

will output:

```
13 42
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> From the *earliest* days of Windows when we had to suffer with the bizarre x86 `{tiny, small, medium, large, huge, gargantuan}` (or whatever they were *actually* called) memory models, `LP` stood for long pointer.

Comment: @paxidiablo Thank you, really cleared things up for me! Just another related question: Does the same idea apply to Get functions that also return a Bool? for example : `BOOL GetCommState (HANDLE hCommDev, LPDCB lpDCB);
`
. Will the lpCommProb be populated? and what's the difference compared to a setter function such as 
`BOOL SetCommState (HANDLE hCommDev, LPDCB lpdcb);`?

Comment: @Some_Tasty_Donuts, depends on the function itself, for which you should check the doco, there's too many to make a blanket assertion :-) Usually, you can only assume the structure has been populated if the return value is true. For SetCommState, it use LPDCB for consistency, the data is not actually changed by the call.

Answer (score 3):

With the Windows API you can usually tell what something is by looking at the variable name and type. The function:

```
BOOL BuildCommDCB (LPCTSTR szSettings, LPDCB lpDCB);
```

Has the types and arguments:

- `LPCTSTR` aka a Long Pointer to C-style (Type) STRing. The type is really a `TCHAR*` which if you have UNICODE defined<sup>1</sup> eventually is of the type `wchar_t*`. The variable name gives you an additional hint (`sz` or string, zero-terminated). A Unicode string would be `LPCWSTR`.
- `LPDCB` which stands for Long Pointer to DCB.  In the header which defines it, the type is defined as `DCB*` (Again the variable name re-inforces that.)

So the function takes a string, and a pointer to a structure, (think of this as a form of passing by reference), and returns a `BOOL`<sup>2</sup> to tell you whether it was successful.  If it wasn't successful, then the values in the `DCB` have not been set, and you shouldn't use them.

The rules are not always followed, but they are often enough that you can translate the API types into C types without too much effort.

For example if I tell you that a `HMODULE` is a module handle, you should know what a `HDEVICE`<sup>3</sup> is.

As always the best place for information about what a function does, and what is expected of it's parameters is MSDN.  The documentation says that the `lpDCB` parameter is,

> A pointer to a DCB structure that receives the information.

To use this knowledge with the example function:

```
DCB dcb;
if (BuildCommDCB(L"Settings", &dcb))
{
    // dcb is valid.
}
else
{
    // dcb is uninitialized garbage
}
```

References:

- [Windows Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [BuildCommDCB at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

*<sup>1</sup>You do have unicode defined, right?*

*<sup>2</sup>A word of warning, `BOOL` is not `bool`*

*<sup>3</sup>A handle to a device of course.*

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363260(v=vs.85).aspx), the second parameter is `_Inout_ LPDCB  lpDCB`, which is a pointer. This situation is like any other pass by pointer/reference case, where information is returned out of function using a reference